# Replace occurrence of string with image in PHP+SQL loop?

Tags: php, sql

This PHP code takes records from my database and displays them. Basically, I want every occurrence of the string "cross" (lowercase only) to be changed to an image that is on my web server.

Records currently look like: `crossJohn Doe`. So when it appears on the page, it should replace cross with the img and keep the rest.

**The code:**

```
$sql = "SELECT DisplayName, LastName, FirstName FROM donor WHERE DonationAmount = 1000 ORDER BY LastName ASC LIMIT 154";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // query
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { // as long as the query returns something, do the calcs.
  $array = array(); // create a variable to hold the information
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ // whule there are results, put them in the array
     $array[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
  }
  $counter = (count($array)); // find the amount of items in the array
  $divisorCount = ceil($counter/2); // column count
  $forEachCount = 1;

  //loop while there are items in the array
  foreach ($array as $row){
     $forEachCount++; //increment counter

     // naming logic
     if (empty($row['DisplayName'])) { // if there is no DisplayName
         if (empty($row['FirstName'])) { // show lastname
             $block[] = "<div class='block'>".$row['LastName']."</div>\n";
         }

         else { //show first + last if no display name
             $block[] = "<div class='block'>".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']."</div>\n";
         }

     } else { // show display name
         $block[] = "<div class='block'>".$row['DisplayName']."</div>\n";
     }


     if($forEachCount > $divisorCount){ //insert each record into a "block"
         $forEachCount = 0;
         end($block);
         $key = key($block);
         $block[$key] .= "</div><div class='column'>"; // insert all "blocks" into a css div
     }
  }
  unset($row,$key,$forEachCount,$divisorCount); //cleanup

  //insert the div and populate it with the blocks
  $output = "<div class='tableContainer'>
    <div class='column'>".implode($block)."</div>
    </div>";
    print_r($output); // display all of it!
    unset($array,$block);
 }else{echo "<p>There are no donors in this category.</p>";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the REPLACE mysql string function might be enough

```
$sql = "SELECT REPLACE(DisplayName,'cross','<img src=\"path/to/image\" />') AS `DisplayName`, REPLACE(LastName,'cross','<img src=\"path/to/image\" />') AS `LastName`, REPLACE(FirstName,'cross','<img src=\"path/to/image\" />') AS `FirstName` FROM donor WHERE DonationAmount = 1000 ORDER BY LastName ASC LIMIT 154";
```

-- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: I currently just get the `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\webtest\screen4.php on line 33`

Comment: stop hiding errors. you get an error and you have report_mode set to be silent about errors. right after connecting, do: $conn->report_mode=MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;

Comment: Okay, I got it to work! Thanks! One last question. How can I do this but have two options? ie if the word is `cross` show image A and if the word is `option2` then do image B?

Comment: this should replace "criss" with image A and "cross" with image B: `REPLACE(REPLACE(DisplayName,'criss','<img src=\"path/to/image\A\" />'),'cross','<img src=\"path/to/image\B\" />') `

Answer (score 0):

you can use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of using `mysqli_fetch_array` and adding another argument to get only the associative one

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

if (stripos('cross',$row['keyname']) !== false)
$row['keyname'] = str_replace('cross','<img src="path/to/image"/>',$row['keyname']);

$array[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
}
```

Comment: Will this only replace the string that says "cross" in the field and not erase the other contents?

Comment: yes try it just replace the 'keyname' with your column name

Comment: it does not change anything. i even changed the `'path/to/image'` to another string to insure it wasn't my image.

Comment: i might specify that records currently look like: `crossJohn Doe`. So when it appears on the page, it should replace `cross` with the img and keep the rest.

Comment: use stripos, not a strpos & strtolower combo :P (it works but it's just weird.)

Comment: it still does not appear to change anything, oddly enough no errors as well